# Translations of "Sur le théorème de Zorn"?

Tags: mathematics, mathematical-logic, set-theory, translations, bourbaki

Are there any translations of the following into English, German, or Russian?

- Nicolas Bourbaki, [Sur le théorème de Zorn](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02036949), Archiv der Mathematik, Volume 2, pages 434–437, November 1949.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe useful Paul Campbell, [THE ORIGIN OF "ZORN'S LEMMA" (1978)](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82199547.pdf)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Campbell cites Bourbaki'39, not Bourbaki'49. The newer 1949 paper has a slightly (?) different claim than the cited 1939 result.